# Module not found: '@material-ui/lab/Breadcrumbs'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Thanks for the help in advance. I am material-ui version 3.0.1 for my react project. When I tried to add breadcrumb I am getting an error like
**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Breadcrumbs'.**
I added @material-ui/lab but the problem still exists. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

package.json

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.0.1",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.13",
```

Comment: delete node_modules, the lock file and the line in your package.json where you have "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.13", then run npm install && npm install @material-ui/lab and see if it works

Comment: thanks for the help..tried but was unsuccessful